# Discord.py - Copying roles from server (name and color)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a copy of servers, like I do >copy in a server and it will create a new server with the same name but adding "backup" to it, then it copies all channels, roles and permissions.

I managed to make the copy channels (and categories) work, permissions I plan to do so later if I can. At the moment, I'm trying to copy the roles (name and color)

```
@SelfBot.command()
async def copy(ctx): # b'\xfc'
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await SelgBot.create_guild(f'backup-{ctx.guild.name}')
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    for g in SelfBot.guilds:
        if f'backup-{ctx.guild.name}' in g.name:
            for c in g.channels:
                await c.delete()
            for cate in ctx.guild.categories:
                x = await g.create_category(f"{cate.name}")
                for chann in cate.channels:
                    if isinstance(chann, discord.VoiceChannel):
                        await x.create_voice_channel(f"{chann}")
                    if isinstance(chann, discord.TextChannel):
                        await x.create_text_channel(f"{chann}")
            print(ctx.guild.roles)
            for role in ctx.guild.roles:
                await g.create_role(name='role', color=RandomColor())
```

It currently creates roles with a random color and with the namee `role`, has anyone ever made something similar and could tell me how can I grab both the name and color of each role of the original server?

Comment: Did you know you can do this exact thing without a discord bot? Discord has a quite new feature called 'Server Tmplates' which allows you to copy to a link (copies roles and there colors, channels, etc.) and whoever clicks that link can create a new server from that template. To make a server template go into server settings and find 'Server Template'.

Comment: @EcksDee No, I did not. Since when is that a thing?

Comment: About 5 months ago, here's the article about it from discord https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041033511-Server-Templates

Comment: But I think you can only get the server template if you're the server owner or have admin/manage server permissions

Comment: Are you aware that selfbots are against the Discord Guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

```
for role in ctx.guild.roles:
                name = role.name
                print(name)
                color = role.colour
                print(color)
                perms = role.permissions
                print(perms)
                await g.create_role(name=name, permissions=perms, colour=color)
```

you can get the name and color by doing `role.name`/`role.colour` :) hope this helps